# Existence of a function satisfies a condition - limit of a function delta-epsilon

Tags: calculus, functions, epsilon-delta

Is there a function such that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow2}f(x)=4$ but it doesn't satisfy that:
$(\exists\delta>0)(\forall\epsilon>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(0<\vert x-2\vert<\delta)\Rightarrow(\vert f(x)-4\vert<\epsilon)$

I tried to look at the contrary which is:
$(\forall\delta>0)(\exists\epsilon>0)(\exists x\in\mathbb{R})(0<\vert x-2\vert<\delta)\wedge(\vert f(x)-4\vert\ge\epsilon)$

Which I guess I need to find a bounded function. I'd like to get an example to help me with my intuition about the this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't you mean $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\exists\delta>0)$ in the first line?

Comment: Nope. but I added that the limit is 4 when $x \rightarrow 2$. Please take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - let $f(x) = 2x$. For any $\delta$, choose $x = 2 + \frac{\delta}{2}$ and $\epsilon = \frac{\delta}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

This is true for
any continuously differentiable function
at a point $a$
with $f'(a) \ne 0$.

Let
$f(a) = b$
and
$f'(a) = c \ne 0$.

Then,
for small $h$,
$\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}
\approx f'(a)
= c$
so
$f(a+h)-f(a)
\approx hf'(a)
$.

Your expression becomes
$(\exists\delta>0)(\forall\epsilon>0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})(0<\vert x-a\vert<\delta)\Rightarrow(\vert f(x)-f(a)\vert<\epsilon)
$

or

$(\exists\delta>0)(\forall\epsilon>0)(0<h<\delta)\Rightarrow(\vert hf'(a)\vert<\epsilon)
$.

However,
the condition states
$(\forall\epsilon>0)$.
Since
$f'(a) \ne 0$,
for any $h > 0$
we can choose
$\epsilon < |hf'(a)|$
so the expression is false.

This is a little sloppy,
but it can be made
more rigorous
by making $f$
have a continuous derivative
and
by choosing a
neighborhood of $a$
such that

$0
\le |\dfrac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)|
\le \frac12|f'(a)|
$
so
$|f(a+h)-f(a)-hf'(a)|
\le \frac12|hf'(a)|
$.

If we then choose
$\epsilon \lt \frac12|hf'(a)|
$
we again get a false statement.